# pangocairo: discolouration on transparent recording surfaces

Tags: cairo, pango, pangocairo

When I use Pango to draw text onto a transparent Cairo recording surface, the text becomes quite heavily discoloured, particularly in the semi-transparent anti-aliased regions. For example, [this image has the correct (top) and incorrect (bottom) rendition of some text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBhA9.png). ([Segment of previous image zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL805.png)).

My question, obviously, is how to get the correct colour rendition when using a transparent recording surface. At least, I am *assuming* this problem has to do with me not understanding the pangocairo pipeline very well. If it's a bug in Pango or Cairo, please do let me know.

Code used to generate the image above:

```
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <pango/pangocairo.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cairo_surface_t *canvas = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
        320, 60);
    cairo_t *cctx = cairo_create(canvas);

    cairo_surface_t *surf = cairo_recording_surface_create(
        CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR_ALPHA, NULL);
    cairo_t *ctx = cairo_create(surf);
    PangoFontDescription *fd = pango_font_description_new();
    PangoLayout *layout = pango_cairo_create_layout(ctx);
    PangoAttrList *attrs = pango_attr_list_new();
    PangoAttribute *at;

    cairo_set_source_rgba(cctx, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_paint(cctx);
    cairo_translate(cctx, 16, 8);

    pango_font_description_set_family(fd, "DejaVu Sans Mono");
    pango_layout_set_font_description(layout, fd);

    pango_layout_set_text(layout, "Bless the Maker and His water", -1);
    pango_layout_set_attributes(layout, attrs);

    at = pango_attr_foreground_new(0, 0xffff, 0xffff);
    pango_attr_list_change(attrs, at);
    at = pango_attr_foreground_alpha_new(0xffff);
    pango_attr_list_change(attrs, at);

    cairo_save(ctx);
    cairo_set_source_rgba(ctx, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_set_operator(ctx, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_paint(ctx);
    cairo_restore(ctx);

    pango_cairo_update_layout(ctx, layout);
    pango_cairo_show_layout(ctx, layout);

    cairo_set_source_surface(cctx, surf, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cctx);

    cairo_save(ctx);
    cairo_set_source_rgba(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_set_operator(ctx, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_paint(ctx);
    cairo_restore(ctx);

    pango_cairo_update_layout(ctx, layout);
    pango_cairo_show_layout(ctx, layout);

    cairo_translate(cctx, 0, 24);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cctx, surf, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cctx);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(canvas, "test.png");

    g_object_unref(layout);
    pango_attr_list_unref(attrs);
    pango_font_description_free(fd);
    cairo_destroy(ctx);
    cairo_destroy(cctx);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf);
    cairo_surface_destroy(canvas);

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** this seems to be caused by something in the video pipeline, and is probably a bug. I can reproduce this on two boxes using AMD video cards, but not on one with an nVidia card. I'm leaving this open in case anybody knows a fix.

Comment: What's the difference between the top and bottom rendering? Put differently: If you know how not to get these colors already, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I want to have an intermediate recording surface so I can do postprocessing on it without affecting my final surface. I _could probably_ get rid of it, but that would vastly complicate my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You example code does not reproduce the problem here. There are no "color fringes" in the resulting image.

If you allow me to guess: Cairo is assuming a subpixel order of RGB for you. According to the documentation for `cairo_subpixel_order_t` this is only used with `CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_SUBPIXEL`. Thus, I would suggest you to do:

```
cairo_font_options_t *opts = cairo_get_font_options(some_cairo_context);
cairo_font_options_set_antialias(opts, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_GRAY); // or _NONE
cairo_set_font_options(some_cairo_context, opts);
cairo_font_options_destroy(opts);
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately this does not make any difference for me, but if you get something different, it may be a bug in cairo/pango/pangocairo after all.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out @uli-schlachter is *almost* correct: you have to set the antialiasing options on a Pango layout object:

```
PangoContext *pctx = pango_layout_get_context(layout);
cairo_font_options_t *opts = cairo_font_options_create();
cairo_font_options_set_antialias(opts, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_GRAY);
pango_cairo_context_set_font_options(pctx, opts);
cairo_font_options_destroy(opts);
```

Comment: Nice find & sorry for missing that function.